# R string encoding cyrillic

Tags: r, encoding, iconv, cyrillic

It seems that I have some cyrillic strings stored as UTF-8 in my database. However I need to restore in cyrillic using R.

For example in database it's stored as:  `"õÆ¿ª®Ï"`. What I need is `Москва`.

I tried some stuff using iconv, but not sure if I need to double-convert the string first:

```
1. iconv(x, "UTF-8", "CP1251")  # I get NA
2. iconv(x, "CP1251", "UTF-8")  # I get  Г»Г»Г» \"ГІГ†ВёГђВ»В°ВёВ»ВЄВї-ГµГ†ВёГ†ВєВ±Гђ\"
```

I assumed I need to restore the string from UTF-8 to cyrillic first, but I get NA.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`enc2native` and `enc2utf8` convert elements of character vectors to the native encoding or UTF-8 respectively, taking any marked encoding into account. They are primitive functions, designed to do minimal copying.